Python script for launching Chrome browser
I am working on a python script to launch chrome browser as well as to bypass cloudfare bot detection (captcha,java rendering, etc.). I am using the script below but chrome is not getting launched.
pip install  undetected-chromedriver

import undetected_chromedriver as uc

def open_webpage(url):
# Set Chrome Options
options = uc.ChromeOptions()

# Switch Undetected ChromeDriver to Headless Mode
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Correct argument for headless mode
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36')

# Proxy settings: Specify your proxy address and port
proxy_address = "socks://username:password@proxyserver:port"
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_address}')

# Create a Chrome browser instance with undetected-chromedriver
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

# Fetch the current user agent to verify
current_user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
print("Current User Agent:", current_user_agent)

# Open the specified URL
driver.get(url)

open_webpage('https://www.indeed.com')

"

Check this post out:
Stack Overflow Post

Its pretty simmilar to InfiniteWolfs answer but the parameters should avoid your program to break

I added same in my code as per InfiniteWolfs but still chrome did not launch, can you please share that code.

First, import the webbrowser using import webbrowser
There are multiple was to do it, but the easiest one is
webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.stackoverflow.com")

This opens the target page in a new tab if there is a browser already, else it should open a new standard browser window.
Here is the documentation, including some other ways to do it that have different results, but this one should do the trick for you.
A working program could look like this:
import webbrowser

userinput = input("Enter your website: ")
webbrowser.open_new_tab(userinput)
print("Opened " + userinput)


Maybe Try using the WebBrowser module?
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://example.com')  # Go to example.com

I'm not to Experienced in python so if this does not work I apologise.
